# Is $\text{Hom}(F,G)$ finite if $F$ and $G$ are endofunctors of the category of finite sets?

Tags: category-theory

Are there endofunctors $F$ and $G$ of the category of finite sets such that there are infinitely many natural transformations from $F$ to $G$?

Same question with $F$ and $G$ contravariant.

Comment: Crossposted on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/331500/461